# Perl: Error installing Lingua::StanfordCoreNLP ("Out of memory!")

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

I tried to install the package [`Lingua::StanfordCoreNLP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::StanfordCoreNLP), but keep receing a simple, yet not very helpful error message:

```
Out of memory!
```

I am using the 5.16 release of DWIMPerl on Windows.

I guess the problem is not related to the package, but to my Perl installation -- does anyone have any thoughts on this?

```
C:\Users\johndoe>cpan Lingua::StanfordCoreNLP
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.202)
Database was generated on Sun, 26 Oct 2014 13:22:19 GMT
Running install for module 'Lingua::StanfordCoreNLP'
Running make for K/KA/KAL/Lingua-StanfordCoreNLP-0.10.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.63)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.042)
Checksum for C:\Dwimperl\cpan\sources\authors\id\K\KA\KAL\Lingua-StanfordCoreNLP
-0.10.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.80)
Out of memory!
```

Comment: I think the obvious question would be "How much memory do you have?"

Comment: It builds here (Strawberry v5.20) from a cpan install. Looks like you're failing to extract the archive. Do you have enough free disk space? Try manually extracting the archive and installing from there.

Comment: Sorry, I was tired. I was using the latest DWIMPerl, not the latest Strawberry Perl. I not installed the latter, and now the problem is that Inline::Java won't install from CPAN (and someone already filed a bug report on this)

Answer (score 0):

CPAN.pm works with a package index. That file is quite large to the point that some memory-constrained systems can't load the entire thing. That's one of the reasons that [cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7040/lib/App/cpanminus.pm) came to be. It doesn't use that huge package index and can work in low-memory environments.